# NgRX Entity : ids are undefined in the State

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, entity, ngrx

I've been trying @ngrx/entity in a dummy "Todo" project, with a single AppModule, a single reducer and a single component. However, I am having issues trying it out.

My actions are pretty straight forward, just some CRUD operations :

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Todo }  from '../../models/todo';


export const CREATE = '[Todo] Create'
export const UPDATE = '[Todo] Update'
export const DELETE = '[Todo] Delete'

export class Create implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE;
    constructor(public todo: Todo) { }
}

export class Update implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE;
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public changes: Partial<Todo>,
      ) { }
}

export class Delete implements Action {
    readonly type = DELETE;
    constructor(public id: string) { }
}

export type TodoActions
= Create
| Update
| Delete;
```

Then my reducer file contains everything I need to handle my entity :

```
import * as actions from './todo.actions';
import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Todo } from '../../models/todo';

export interface TodosState extends EntityState<Todo> {}
export const todoAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Todo>();

export const initialState: TodosState = todoAdapter.getInitialState();

export function todoReducer(state: TodosState = initialState, action: actions.TodoActions) {
    console.log("Got new action", action);
    switch(action.type) {
        case actions.CREATE:
            return todoAdapter.addOne(action.todo, state);
        case actions.UPDATE:
            return todoAdapter.updateOne({
                id: action.id,
                changes: action.changes
            }, state);
        case actions.DELETE:
            return todoAdapter.removeOne(action.id, state);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const {
    selectIds,
    selectEntities,
    selectAll,
    selectTotal
} = todoAdapter.getSelectors();
```

In my `app.module.ts` file, I am doing the following :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { todoReducer } from './reducers/todo.reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      todo: todoReducer
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25}),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally, in my `app.component.ts`, I am simply trying to create two TODOs :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import * as fromTodo from './reducers/todo.reducer';
import { Todo } from '../models/todo';
import { Create } from './reducers/todo.actions';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    `,
    styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public todos: Observable<Todo[]>;


    constructor(private store: Store<fromTodo.TodosState>) {
        this.store.dispatch(new Create({
            title: "Test todo",
            content: "This is a test todo",
            date: new Date()
        }))
        this.store.dispatch(new Create({
            title: "Test todo 2",
            content: "This is another todo",
            date: new Date()
        }))
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.todos = this.store.select(fromTodo.selectAll);
    }

}
```

However, after running this, I inspected the `Redux DevTools`. I saw that it only creates the first TODO, and its id is "undefined".

[image: App state after running the app and dispatching both events]

My `console.log` in my reducer displays `@ngrx/store/init`, as well as both `[TODO]` Create actions

Moreover, if I try to `ngFor | async` through my `todos` in my component, I get various errors depending on what I try ("Cannot read 'map' property of undefined" mainly).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research, I noticed that `@ngrx/entity` uses the `id` property of the model you use.
In my case, my `Todo` model did not have any `id` property, so `@ngrx/entity` could not handle my entities.
I thought it generated ids internally, but apparently it doesn't.

So the fix to this issue is to add an `id` property to the model, and auto-generate it each time you add an item to the state.

There is a [Angular2 UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-uuid) module for example.

In my case, I am using `ngrx` with `AngularFire2`, which has a `createId()` method : `const id = this.afs.createId()`. Then I can add it to the item I want to add, and then store it in my Firestore database.

Comment: Thank you man, It saved my day. I was facing the same issue.

Comment: I have the same error "cannot read ids of undefined" on the state object in the ngrx-entity.mjs file, even with my entity containing the id property. :(

Comment: in my case, a very similar problem was caused because of the fact that I didn't import the Effects and the Store modules to the module that I was using. After adding the imports to the used module - everything started working normally.